# Alembic conditional based on database engine

Tags: python, migration, alembic

Can alembic run slightly different migration code based on database type?  For example, run `ALTER TABLE object AUTO_INCREMENT = 6000;` only on MySQL, but skip this for SQLite?

Some background: We're using alembic to run migrations.  On many dev setups, we use sqlite, and on production we use mysql.  On production, we want to start some Primary keys at a particular value, but on dev setups using sqlite, this is not possible and not needed, so we can skip this step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to get the engine name from the bind.  I added the following to my migration:

```
def upgrade():
    # create table call
    bind = op.get_bind()
    if bind.engine.name == 'mysql':
        op.execute("ALTER TABLE object AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000")
    else:
        print("Skipping setting initial ID value")
```

Comment: If it can help someone: the name to use for Postgres is `'postgresql'`, not `'postgres'`.